# Setting up a shader for RTS construction grid visibility (around cursor)

Tags: unity, shaders, grid

I've set up a shader, thanks to the good help of @DMGregory over at : [Draw animating grid with terrain deformation and variable colors](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/182576/draw-animating-grid-with-terrain-deformation-and-variable-colors/)

here's what I got so far :

[image: messed up shader]

here's what it's supposed to look like :

[image: desired result shader]

here's what my shader code looks like as it stands :

[image: full current shader]

forgive my non-2K + screen it's only a 1080p but this is the full shader.

here's each bit in isolation :

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

[image: image3]

[image: image4]

[image: image5]

here's the main options for the node :

[image: settings]

If I set surface to transparent...

I get a much better result :

[image: shader test]

yet still not what I want because the grid area fades out immediately instead of staying at the center of the cube :

[image: result]

also the corner clearly has a green and red line overlap when line should only ever be red or green.

this is the mock file that I'm currently using for buildable and non buildable area :

[image: mock buildable texture]

it's 256x256 (the size of my map) for now because I want to start small (where 1px maps to one unity square on the terrain of 1 unit) before I move on to the real deal which should be a 3584x3584 Texture 2D (where 1px corresponds to 1/14th of a unity unit).

I want my grid to be 1/14th of an digit. eg cell one is (in diagonal) from (0.0f, 0.0f) to (0.14f, 0.14f).

I've got preliminary code which will serve to generate this texture 2D programmatically :

```
    editable2DconstructibleMap = new Texture2D(256, 256, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false);
    constructionGrid = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GridViewer").GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();

    // fill texture color corresponding to navMesh
    for (int x = 0; x < editable2DconstructibleMap.width; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < editable2DconstructibleMap.height; y++) {
            NavMeshHit hit;
            if (NavMesh.SamplePosition(new Vector3(x * 1.0f, 0f,y * 1.0f), out hit, 1.0f, NavMesh.AllAreas))
            {
                editable2DconstructibleMap.SetPixel(x, y, Color.white);
            }
            else
            {
                editable2DconstructibleMap.SetPixel(x, y, Color.black);
            }
        }
    }
    constructionGrid.sharedMaterial.SetTexture("BuildableMask", editable2DconstructibleMap);
```

Here I'm using the navMesh which itself is automatically generated based on terrain slope.

I target each point of the map and see if it falls in or out of the navmesh.

Instead of redrawing this texture 2D when a building is placed and placement becomes impossible. I think I'll simply programmatically edit the 2D texture to add the new black pixels whilst the navmesh will be updated independently.
Anyways, I guess the green + red overlap issue comes from my texture2D being currently too small, but if I don't know yet what one pixel corresponds to, I'll have trouble getting this right.

---

#### Update :

so changing the texture to one of 3584x3584 did not help. I still have the exact same behavior.

So basically what did I get wrong in following the instructions from the other answer?

Comment: In the Transform node at the start of the Radial Fade block, you're using the Model matrix instead of its inverse.

Comment: yup. indeed. my bad. that works alot better. Any tips on mapping my texture to the right scale? or will it automatically match my  3584x3584 with the exact terrain size?

Comment: Is it solved, or are there still issues to fix?

Comment: the texture generation code, does it seem like an appropriate approach to you, and will the size  3584x3584 work?

Comment: Try using a buildable mask that's a power of 2 in size (so Unity doesn't resample it to a different resolution by default) and set it to nearest-neighbour / point filtering.

Comment: ok for the power of two (although that'll be difficult for the iterative loop + 1/14th rule but I'll make it work) and as for  " nearest-neighbour / point filtering" that's a mode I can select from a drop-down I take it? but where?

Comment: does this seem right for geting my 1/14th map : https://imgur.com/i0U0SIH ?

Comment: No. Your shader should work in grid space — the same grid should be used for forming the lines as for reading from the mask texture, so you should not introduce extra divisors. [As for the filter mode, you can find that documented here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture-filterMode.html)

Comment: (that specific doc link is very very parsimonious) but ok thank you so much that is all the help I could have ever hoped for and then much more!