# Drawing a deferred decal when the camera clips its bounding geometry

Tags: shaders, camera, terrain, clipping

[I have a building grid effect that I decal onto my terrain using a cube that moves to follow the cursor](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/182576/draw-animating-grid-with-terrain-deformation-and-variable-colors/).

[image: shader cube]

You can see if the camera gets too close to the cube, it gets clipped by the camera's near plane:

[image: camera clipping issue]

See the clipping just starting here:

[image: camera clipping]

I'd like to find a solution to this as the camera may be this low to the ground or lower upwards of 50% of the time during gameplay. (the rest of the time you would use the view from above, as illustrated by the clip I provided).

Is there any way to solve this problem?

I'd like to correctly render the cube's shader despite/while clipping with the camera.

is this possible and how?

.

.

.

#### EDIT & UPDATE :

---

I'm implementing camera-to-cubemesh clipping detection and already having issues :

```
public class Grid : MonoBehaviour
{
    #region
    [Header("First point to Camera Controller")]
    [SerializeField]
    public CameraController CameraController;
    MeshRenderer constructionGrid;
    private Camera cam;

    private void Start()
    {
        cam = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainCamera").GetComponent<UnityEngine.Camera>();
        constructionGrid = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GridViewer").GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Plane[] frustumPlanes = GeometryUtility.CalculateFrustumPlanes(cam);
        if (GeometryUtility.TestPlanesAABB(frustumPlanes, constructionGrid.bounds))
        {
            Debug.Log("Clipping");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Not");
        }
    }
```

This always logs "Cliping" whether clipping or not.

If I add a meshCollider to the shadercube the same happens but the shadercube jitters all over the place.

I can't figure out clipping detection.

Comment: I don't have time to write a full answer just this moment, but the basic idea is: check if your camera/near plane touch the volume of your cube. If so, swap to an alternate material that inverts the culling to draw back faces, and inverts the depth test to draw only where it's behind the surface. Then it doesn't matter that you've clipped into the front faces of the cube, because you're drawing the far side through the terrain instead.

Comment: I think I kinda grasp the idea. I'm gonna have to google a lot though because I don't understand culling, ect but basically I should switch the shader to render to the inside faces instead of the outside faces when clipping? 

I'll edit my post to remove my old ideas.